# How to display dynamicly created MySql Table content in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am really really new in PHP and MySql, I ve searched some solution for my issue but i couldnt find anything and i am here first time to asking you.

I create dynamicly MySQL tables and list them, the issue is i want to display cointain of each table on the page 
    include("config.php");

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM pendejas";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
if ( //     exclude some table to show 
        ($row[0] <> 'pasajeros') &&
    ($row[0] <> 'usuarios') &&
    ($row[0] <> 'grupos')
       )

echo " $row[0]". "<br>"; // list tables 
// This code displays table list but 
// I need to show contain of each table listed on this page but how :( 
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: as said by Machavity, mysql_ is deprecated, so I add the mysqli version :)

To display each table name with its content, you can replace

```
echo " $row[0]". "<br>";
```

By the following code:

Mysqli_* version:

```php
$my = new Mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'mydb');
$sql = 'SELECT * from '.$row[0];
$res_content = $my->query($sql);
if ($res_content)
{

    echo '<table><caption> datas of '.$row[0].'</caption>';
    while($row_content = $res_content->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row_content as $field => $value)
        {
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Deprecated version:

```php
$sql = 'SELECT * from '.$row[0];
$res_content = mysql_query($sql);
if ($res_content)
{

    echo '<table><caption> datas of '.$row[0].'</caption>';
    while($row_content = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_content))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row_content as $field => $value)
        {
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

This is the basic code, but maybe you will have to adapt it to your needs (like adding a query `SHOW FIELDS` to display column titles)

Comment: THANKS A LOT !! worked excellent !  just i have to make some modification as you said !

Comment: Also, keep in mind Machavity's advice : mysql_* is deprecated for a while. You can safely change the functions you use by mysqli_* .  Check also the php functions mysqli_prepare (to use with mysqli_stmt_bind_param and mysqli_stmt_bind_result) to make your queries secure

Answer (score 0):

First off, `mysql_` is depreciated so you might want to switch to [mysqli](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Second, when you're using the procedural methods, you have to create a connection pointer with [mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and then pass that along in your code

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password, 'mydb');
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM pendejas";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```